# When reading a file in C, does the file needs to be in the same folder as the program? And if so, is there any way to read a file in another folder?

Tags: c, file

This is part of my  program

```
        printf("file name?\n");
        scanf("%s", name);
        ptr = fopen(name, "r");
        if(ptr == NULL){
        printf("error opening the file\n");
        }
```

It always says error. Any way of  solving this? Thanks

Comment: Does the file exist? No, it doesn't have to be in the same folder.

Comment: hello arkadiusz , thank you. The file does exists, its a .txt type file

Comment: hello Kristianmitk haw can i provide the pathname? thank you

Comment: @cesarcol: It depends on what OS do you use and of course on the structure of your filesystem. How are you providing the filename now?

Comment: When the program asks for the file If the file is yellow.txt I write yellow.txt. I also tryed typing yellow and "yellow.txt". Was that your question? Thank you.

Comment: `yellow.txt` is enough, do not add double quotes. And does this file exist in the current directory?

Comment: Nope. Does it need to be?

Comment: Yes, it has to exist if you open it for reading with `r`. What OS do you use? Linux, Window, Mac, something different?

Comment: oh ok thank you  when i asked if it had to be in same folder i meant directory. (im kind of new to this). my computer is a mac.

Answer (score 2):

> When reading a file in C, does the file needs to be in the same folder
>   as the program?

No, it doesn't.

> And if so, is there any way to read a file in another folder?

You need to provide a path to the file - either absolute or relative
to the current working directory.  The specific format of the path depends on
the OS you use and its value depends of course on the structure of
your filesystem.

In your case, however, the error occurs because you try to open a file
that does not exist.  If you open file for reading, that is if you use
`"r"` in the second parameter of `fopen()` the file has to exist before you open it
- it will not be created by system as it would be if you used `"w"` or
`"a"`.  See the description of `fopen()` function in C standard
[here](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.5.3):

> ```
> r                     open text file for reading
> w                     truncate to zero length or create text file for writing
> ```